# Web page does not preserve newlines

Tags: php, javascript, newline, stringification

Building a web app that includes several contentEditable divs. The users add stuff to the div's, clicks the save button, which saves all the data from each div to a json object. That goes through `JSON.stringify` to a mysql database as a TEXT (uploaded with php via `mysql_real_escape_string()` ). When loaded it goes back to `JSON.parse` and then via javascript and jquery is placed back where it was. 
The only issue is that newline characters are not replaced.
Is there a quick fix to this?

Comment: Is the data going from a textarea to a div?

Comment: The data is going from div to mysql back to div.

Answer (score 3):

New line characters in HTML are ignored.  What you need is `<br/>` tags to replace the newlines, and PHP has the perfect function for you.  [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) will replace the newlines with these tags and should return the output you're expecting.

```
$string = "some text\nwith\nnewlines";
echo nl2br($string);
// should return "some text<br/>with<br/>newlines"
```